# javascript error: arguments[0].setAttribute is not a function

Tags: javascript, protractor

Following function is giving me an error -

```
javascript error: arguments[0].setAttribute is not a function
```

I really don't know what am I doing wrong -

```
export async function highlightElement(webElement: ElementFinder) {
    await browser.driver.executeScript(
        'arguments[0].setAttribute("style", arguments[1]);', webElement.getWebElement, 'color: Red; border: 2px solid red;').
        then(resp => {
            return element;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Error highlighting element' + err);
        });
}
```

I am trying to highlight the web element on the page using it. I am using single quotes due to tslint here. The value I am passing to it is an elementFinder like

```
element(by.xpath('//vtable/div/table/tbody'))
```

Comment: I guess Protractor tries to parse  `arguments` in the context of `executeScript`, not in the context you've intended.

Comment: @Teemu, probably yes. Any suggestions as how to handle it?

Comment: Extract the arguments to their own variables and pass those variables instead.

Comment: @Teemu, do you mean something like `const arg0 = 'arguments[0].setAttribute("style", arguments[1]);';` and `const arg1 = 'color: Red; border: 2px solid red;';` and passing `executeScript(arg0, webElement.getWebElement, arg1)`?

Comment: No, you've to resolve the live arguments in that function which passes them forward.

Comment: @Teemu, would appreciate if you could post an answer as I am unable to make out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It should be `webElement.getWebElement()`, rather than `webElement.getWebElement` , second you should use `!important` in style value in case other css value has high priority.

```
export async function highlightElement(webElement: ElementFinder) {
    await browser.driver.executeScript(
            'arguments[0].setAttribute("style", arguments[1]);', 
            webElement.getWebElement(), 
            'border: 2px solid red !important;'
        ).
        then(resp => {
            return webElement;
        }).catch(err => {
            console.log('Error highlighting element' + err);
        });
}
```

Comment: Interesting. I got away with the error and don't see any error now. But some how don't see the element getting highlighted even. I was trying to highlight a table. Table is getting identified though.

Comment: please try `<the table>.setAttribute("style", 'color: Red; border: 2px solid red;')` in DevTool manually to check it work as your expect.

Comment: add `!important` in style value to make your given value with highest priority

Comment: Okays, trying now.

Comment: My bad, I was using a wrong object. It works mate. Thanks a bunch.

Answer (score 0):

Disable the lint and Try the below one

```
/* tslint:disable */
    browser.executeScript("arguments[0].setAttribute('style',arguments[1])", webElement, "color: Red; border: 2px solid red;");
/* tslint:enable */
```

Hope it help you

Comment: I can't disable tslint as that's required.

Comment: You can disable for that particular line. use `/* tslint:disable */ - Disable all rules for the rest of the file
/* tslint:enable */ - Enable all rules for the rest of the file`

Comment: It's not working. TS Lint has nothing to do with it by the way.

Comment: OKay then. Did you try with single queots

Comment: Yes, error is same. Tried with both. Seems some protractor related.